# Create back button

Tags: objective-c

How do I create a custom back button on one of my storyboards, when I do a segue and I say push it creates a back button on Mac with but when I do a modal or model it does not create a back button?

Answer (score 1):

Modally presented view controllers do not automatically get close buttons.

`self.navigationController.leftBarButtonItem = ...`

A pushed view controller will automatically create a back button if the navigation controller is shown.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create your own back button. In the view controller that you have presented via the modal transition, you have to put a toolbar on it.  Put it at the top and if using autolayout set the constraints top, both sides and height. Then place a barbuttonitem in the toolbar. You can select a system button like done or cancel. Make sure the new view controller is the class that you created. Now you can control drag from the barbuttonitem to your .h file and connect an IBAction. Call it dismiss or something like that. In that method call [self dismiss viewcontroller:animated completion:nil].  This will bring you back to the original view controller. I am not a my computer right now so I am not sure the exact wording of the dismiss method, but it will auto fill for you. Good luck.

Comment: @omied badr,  if you have any questions just ask.

Answer (score 0):

As Douglas explained, you need to create property of the button (UIButton or BarButtonItem) and in the viewcontroller .m file connect

```
- (IBAction)backButton:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

with the button. This will dismiss the current view controller and bring you back to the previous one :)